# How to read the orientation sensor data in Android at a specified rate?

Tags: android, multithreading, orientation, accelerometer, sensors

I want to read the orientation sensor value at a specified rate say every 100 ms. How can I achieve this  and how to specify the rate of 100 ms ?  I am using the following code snippet to read the orientation sensor :

```
  final public SensorEventListener listener=new SensorEventListener() {
   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "in sensor changed");

  if (e.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
      OrientationX=e.values[0];
      OrientationY=e.values[1];
      OrientationZ=e.values[2];
      message_orientation = "OrientationX ="+String.valueOf(OrientationX)+", OrientationY   ="+String.valueOf(OrientationY)+", OrientationZ ="+String.valueOf(OrientationZ);            
      Log.d(TAG, "Orientation value is "+message_orientation);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

from [the Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html)

mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL is the rate

and as the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int,%20android.os.Handler%29) explains:

The rate sensor events are delivered at. This is only a hint to the system. Events may be received faster or slower than the specified rate. Usually events are received faster. The value must be one of SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SENSOR_DELAY_UI, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, or SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST. or, the desired delay between events in microsecond.

Comment: David: it does not specify a specific rate that I want to pass as argument or specify. Is there a way to satisfy the specified rate?

Comment: @Shan - the third argument is the rate, in microseconds. So 100 milliseconds = 100000 microseconds.

Comment: @David: Thanks !  So, I can set the SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL to 100000 to get the required rate. Where should I modify that ? I am very new to Andoid, it may be dumb to ask that.

Comment: no. SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL is only a static variable living in the SensorManager class. What you want to do is replace SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL by 100000. And you could accept my answer as valid.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some approximations based on tested results:

> ```
> Accelerometer, SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST: 18-20 ms
> Accelerometer, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME: 37-39 ms
> Accelerometer, SENSOR_DELAY_UI: 85-87 ms
> Accelerometer, SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL: 215-230 ms
> Orientation Sensor, SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST: 16-17 ms
> Orientation Sensor, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME: 37-39 ms
> Orientation Sensor, SENSOR_DELAY_UI: 77 ms
> Orientation Sensor, SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL: 224-225 ms
> ```

You can also define your own rate, for example 100ms.

> int READINGRATE = 100000 %time in us
>   mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mLinearAccelerometer,
>   READINGRATE);

However the rate is just an approximation, if you need an accurate rate it is better to use a timer and get the value every 100ms.